# command runs fine as standalone but not with nohup

Tags: python-3.x, bash, multiprocessing, nohup

I have a python script I am trying to run using nohup.

This script runs perfectly with:

`python3 script.py`

But when run as:

`nohup python3 script.py &`

It gets stuck.
This script uses [python multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)
and gets stuck at
`mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())`

Comment: Is it the `nohup` or the `&` that causes it to get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

One of the first things to check is, that if your python script is running.
If it is, the problem is because of buffering.

Run your command as:

`nohup python3 -u script.py &`